# From change of variables formula to $\int_{\varphi(a)}^{\varphi (b)}f(v)\,\mathrm d v= \int_a^b f (\varphi (u)) \varphi ' (u) \, \mathrm d u$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, change-of-variable

Let $a,b \in \mathbb R$ with $a < b$. Let $U := (a, b)$. Let $f:U \to \mathbb R$ be integrable. Let $\varphi:U \to \mathbb R$ be injective and continuously differentiable.

- By [change of variables formula](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_multiple_variables), we have
  $$
  \int_{\varphi (U)} f(v) \, \mathrm d v = \int_a^b f (\varphi (u)) |\varphi ' (u)| \, \mathrm d u.
  \tag{1}
  $$
- In [this](https://www.math.toronto.edu/jko/MAT136_week_3.pdf) note, we have
  $$
  \int_{\varphi (a)}^{\varphi (b)} f(v) \, \mathrm d v =  \int_a^b f (\varphi (u)) \varphi ' (u) \, \mathrm d u.
  \tag{2}
  $$

Could you explain how to go from (1) to (2)?

Comment: Consider the two cases of (weakly) increasing and decreasing $\phi$. (Why are these the only cases?) Then apply the definition of the notation $\int_a^b$, being careful with what it means when the lower limit is larger than the upper limit (again, by definition).

Comment: $\varphi$ is injective thus montonous on $U$. It implies that its derivative is non-negative or non-positive. Look at those two case and you have your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\varphi$ is increasing, there is no difference between those two expressions.

Now, suppose that $\varphi$ is decreasing and let $[c,d]=\varphi\bigl([a,b]\bigr)$. Then
\begin{align}
\int_{\varphi(U)}f(v)\,dv&=\int_c^df(v)\,dv\\
&=-\int_d^cf(v)\,dv.\\
&=-\int_{\varphi(a)}^{\varphi(b)}f(v)\,dv
\end{align}
whereas
$$
\int_a^bf(\varphi(u))|\varphi'(u)|\,du=-\int_a^bf(\varphi(u))\varphi'(u)\,du.
$$
And $\int_{\varphi(a)}^{\varphi(b)}f(v)\,dv=\int_a^bf(\varphi(u))\varphi'(u)\,du$.

Comment: Since $\varphi(U)=[c,d]$, you should write that $$
\int_{\varphi(U)}f(v)\,dv=\int_c^df(v)\,dv=-\int_d^cf(v)\,dv=\\=-\int_{\varphi(a)}^{\varphi(b)}f(v)\,dv\;.$$

Comment: @Angelo I have followed your suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: Also, the assumption that $\phi([a,b])$ is a closed interval follows from the fact that $\phi$ is continuous, $[a,b]$ is an interval and thus connected, and that $\phi([a,b])$ is connected. In $\mathbb R$, the connected sets are intervals. Furthermore, $[a,b]$ is compact, so $\phi([a,b])$ is compact and is hence a closed (and bounded) interval. Injectivity ensures the endpoints are $\phi(a)$ and $\phi(b)$ (or vice versa).

Comment: And ideally you should justify why these are the only teo cases.